# How to pass database queryset objects from class based views to templates in Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I am building a web app.I am trying to pass a queryset from a class based view to templates as variables in Django 2.0. But the variables were not displayed at http://localhost:8000/joblist/. Other text are displayed on this url routing, but the queryset objects are not displayed as variables on the page. The models.py and the database work fine, and the database is populated with ~10k records. What am i missing? I would also like to know the advantages of class based views over function based views in simple words. Thank you. 
My `views.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView
from joblist.models import Jobs

def index(request):
    context = {}
    html = TemplateResponse(request,'welcome.html',context)
    return HttpResponse(html.render())

class JobList(ListView):
    model=Job
    context_object_name = 'job_title'
    queryset=Job.objects.all()
    template_name = 'job_list.html'

class JobDetail(DetailView):

    model = Job
    context_object_name = 'job_detail'
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    template_name = 'job_detail.html'
```

My template: `joblist.html`

```
{% extends 'welcome.html' %}
<h1> Job Title </h1>

<ul>
    {% for job in object_list %}
        <li>{{ job_title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: The context variable for the list was set to `context_object_name = 'job_title'`. Use `{% for job in job_title %}` in the template to iterate over the queryset.

Comment: I used `job_title` as a variable in the template as you suggested, or i don't know where to place it?

Comment: The template has no context variable for the name `object_list` - you renamed the variable to `job_title`. No `object_list` no iteration - no `{{job_title}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this code for iterating context_object_name in list. Thanks

```
 <ul>
        {% for job in job_title %}
            <li>{{ job.model_field_name }}</li>
        {% endfor %} 
 </ul>
```

Comment: `<ul>
    {% for job in job_title %}
        <li>{{ job.model_field_name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>`

Answer (score 3):

You have set the context_object_name to "job_title", so thats what you should use in the template, not "object_list" which is the default. job_list would seem a more sensible name.

```
<ul>
    {% for job in job_title %}
        <li>{{ job }}</li>
    {% endfor %} 
</ul>
```

Comment: `job_list` does indeed make more sense. In fact, as `model` has already been set on the view, `job_list` will be included in the context by default (`object_list` will also be present). See [`MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/views/generic/list.py#L115-L124).

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your code as below:

```
<ul>
  {% for job in job_title %}
    <li>{{ job.model_field_name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```